# Any way to resize text on the back of Windows Phone 8 Live Tiles?

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm using a [Flip Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206971.aspx) for my tiles. On the MSDN page the text is seen to wrap, as well as be a smaller size.

This is not representative of behaviour I'm seeing in my live tiles. I can get a maximum of 3 lines, of large text, on the Wide live tile. The text does not wrap. This happens on all the different screen sizes of emulators. Frustratingly, I can get 4 lines of text on the Medium live tile, but the additional line of content is too long to fit there anyway so I don't include it.

I update my tiles periodically using a scheduled task:

```
Earthquake latest = quakes.First();
newTileData = new FlipTileData
{
    Title = String.Format(AppResources.LiveTileTitleFormat, quakes.Count),
    BackTitle = String.Format(AppResources.LiveTileTitleFormat, quakes.Count),
    BackContent = String.Format(AppResources.LiveTileBackContentFormat,  latest.FormattedMagnitude, latest.FormattedDepth),
    WideBackContent = String.Format(AppResources.LiveTileWideBackContentFormat, latest.FormattedMagnitude, latest.FormattedDepth, latest.RelativeLocation)
};

ShellTile tileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
if (tileToFind != null)
{
    tileToFind.Update(newTileData);
}
```

The emulator on the left is attempting to show 4 lines.
The emulator on the right is showing the text not wrapping.

[image]

So, is there any way to force a fourth line, or specify a smaller font size, or both? I suspect there isn't, and the MSDN article is simply showing Windows 8 (not WP8) live tiles.

Comment: No that is not possible sorry. A solution is to write the text on the tile-picture yourself instead of using the built-in properties.

Comment: It appears that you are right. Rather disappointing. If you'd like to to add this as the answer I'll accept it - "not possible" is a valid answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to resize text on WP8 tiles. You can fake it by creating an image and placing that on the tile instead:

1. Create a user control that accommodate an image control and Text block
2. Assign you tile image to image control and the text with desire size to text block.
3. Then create a snapshot of the control through following code.
4. use this image for implementing tile generation.

   ```
    private WriteableBitmap RenderControlAsImage(UserControl element)
    {
       element.UpdateLayout();
       element.Measure(new Size(element.Width, element.Height));
       element.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, element.Width, element.Height));
       return new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
    }
   ```

Comment: I had trouble with this and wp8, i needed to call the element inside to get the width and height otherwise i got NaN `element.Measure(new Size(element.Content.DesiredSize.Width, element.Content.DesiredSize.Height));`